# IPV6 Connect error 10049(A-GAIN!)

Tags: sockets, network-programming, ipv6

So I configured windows 8 firewall to allow IPV6 outbound and inbound connections as a precautionary measure but whenever I try to connect to *either* are remote host *or* to my own machine using the loopback address(to an ipv6 server application running simultaneously)the connect function FAILS with error 10049 regardless of what port I choose. Is this a network configuration problem? IP4 works just fine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>


#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN






#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <IPTypes.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"iphlpapi.lib")



using namespace std;


static int MAXPENDING = 5;

void set_interface(SOCKET s, DWORD Index);






int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int Result;
    int  optv = 1;
    char *optval = (char*)&optv;
    int  optlen = sizeof(optval);
    DWORD Index = 22;       
    bool connected = false;
    string exit = "quit";
    string name;
    sockaddr_in6 c_addr;
    c_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;

    char buffer[1024];







    Result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (Result != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }





    SETUP:

        SOCKET connector;
        connector = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (connector == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(connector);
            return 1;
        }









        cout << "Enter host name(URL): ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << endl;   



        char *hostname = const_cast<char*>(name.c_str());   

        if(inet_pton(AF_INET6,hostname,&c_addr.sin6_addr)<0){
            printf("InetPton() function failed with error: %d/n",GetLastError());
            closesocket(connector);
            return 1;
        }





        string p;
        char *hostport;
        int p0rt;
        cout << "Enter the port number you wish to connect on: " ;
        cin >> p;
        cout << endl;   
        hostport = const_cast<char*>(p.c_str());
        p0rt = atoi(hostport);

        if(!( 0 < p0rt  &&  p0rt < 65,536)){
            cout << "Error: port number must be greater than 0 and less than 65,536. " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Re-enter the port number you wish to connect on: " ;
            cin >> p;
            cout << endl;   
            hostport = const_cast<char*>(p.c_str());
            p0rt = atoi(hostport);

        }else{
            c_addr.sin6_port = htons(p0rt);
        }








    if(connect(connector,(sockaddr*)&c_addr,sizeof(c_addr))<0){
            printf("Connect failed with error: %d\n",GetLastError());
            string cmd;
            cout << endl;
            cout <<"Try again? Type 'y' to reattempt connection or type any other key to exit: ";
            cin >> cmd;
            cout << endl;
            if(cmd=="y"){

                goto SETUP;
            }else {
                goto QUIT;
            }


    }else{
        connected = true;
        cout << "Connected to host " << hostname << " on port " << c_addr.sin6_port << endl;
        cout << "Type 'quit' to exit the program " << endl;
    }

    while(connected==true){

       int nbr = 0;


       cout << endl;
       cout << ">";
       scanf("%s",buffer);
       cout << endl;

       string str(buffer);

       if(str==exit){

           connected = false;
           goto QUIT;
       }




       long nbs = send(connector,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
       if(nbs < 0){
            printf("send() failed", GetLastError());
            goto QUIT;
       }

       while(nbr < nbs){
            nbr = recv(connector,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
            if(nbr < 0){
                printf("recv() failed", GetLastError());
                goto QUIT;

            }else if(nbr==0){
                printf("recv() failed: connection closed prematurely", GetLastError());
                goto QUIT;              
            }else if(nbr > 0){
                cout << endl;
                cout << ">> ";
                printf(buffer);
                cout << endl;
            }

       }



    }


    QUIT:

        if (closesocket(connector) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }


    WSACleanup();

    return 0;




};


void set_interface(SOCKET s, DWORD Index){




        MIB_IF_ROW2 T2;
        NET_LUID   ID;
        DWORD ptbuflen = (DWORD)sizeof(T2); 


        ConvertInterfaceIndexToLuid(Index,&ID);
        T2.InterfaceLuid = ID;
        GetIfEntry2(&T2);



        if(WSAIoctl(s,SIO_ASSOCIATE_HANDLE,&T2,ptbuflen,NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL)>0){
            printf("WSAIoctl() function failed with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            closesocket(s);


        }

        if(WSAIoctl(s,SIO_TRANSLATE_HANDLE,&T2,ptbuflen,NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL)>0){
            printf("WSAIoctl() function failed with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            closesocket(s);


        }

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bind() fails with windows socket error 10049](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366048/bind-fails-with-windows-socket-error-10049)

Answer (score 1):

You need to zero out the portion of the `sockaddr_in6` that you are not using.  Zero out the enire thing first, then fill in the portions you need.

If the user fails to enter a valid port the first time, you are not validating the new port entered the second time, and you are not assigning that second port value to the `sockaddr_in6` at all.  You should be doing your validation in a loop, and then assign the final accepted value to the `sockaddr_in6`.

You are using `inet_pton()` when you should be using [`getaddrinfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx) instead.  `inet_pton()` only converts an IP address string to its binary format.  It will not resolve a hostname to an IP.  `getaddrinfo()` does that resolution instead, and it also supports converting IP address strings as well (specify the `AI_NUMERICHOST` flag in the `hints` parameter to get that behavior).

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. But what about the sockaddr_in6 struct? I need to to specify the scopeID so it knows what interface use.

Comment: No, you do not need to specify a scope ID. If you want to connect using a specific interface, then `bind()` the socket to that interface's local IP before then calling `connect()`.

Comment: I was able to specify the connect interface using the WSAIoctl() function. Appreciate yer help. FTR: I scrubbed out the sockaddr_in6 struct and used an addrinfo struct with the getaddrinfo() and that is what did the trick.