# how to work with c++ sockets over the internet?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, server

So I've been learning about socket programming in c++ and I can successfully create a basic client-server socket application that works on a local machine but I don't know how to get it to work over the internet like creating a chat application or something similar, I saw people talking about UDP wall punching to use internet sockets but I can't seem to find any information or tutorial on how to do such thing.

Server Script

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << ">>>WINSOCK SEREVER\n";

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;


    addrinfo *Results = NULL;
    if (!getaddrinfo("41.143.215.7", "255", &hints, &Results)){
        cout << "->Ready To Create SOCKET and bind Address\n";
        SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        listenSocket = socket(Results->ai_family, Results->ai_socktype, Results->ai_protocol);
        if (listenSocket != INVALID_SOCKET){
            cout << "->Socket is created...";
            if (bind(listenSocket, Results->ai_addr, Results->ai_addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR){
                cout << "and bind successfuly\n [" << getsockname(listenSocket, Results->ai_addr, (int *)Results->ai_addrlen) << "]\n";
                if (!listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN)){
                    cout << "->waiting for Client to connect";
                    SOCKET clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
                    clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
                    if (clientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET){
                        cout << "->Client Has Connected\nWaiting for Messages...";
                        int iResult = 1;
                        while(true){
                            char BufferRcv[9000];
                            iResult = recv(clientSocket, BufferRcv, 9000, 0);
                            if (iResult > 0){
                                cout << "\nBuffer Received : \n" << BufferRcv;
                            }   
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            else { cout << "Error Binding Socket!!!"; }

        }

    }



    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Client Script

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << ">>>WINSOCK CLIENT\n";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    addrinfo *Results = NULL;

    if (!getaddrinfo("41.143.215.79", "255", &hints, &Results)){
        cout << "->Ready To Create SOCKET and connect to SERVER\n";
        SOCKET connectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        connectSocket = socket(Results->ai_family, Results->ai_socktype, Results->ai_protocol);
        if (connectSocket != INVALID_SOCKET){
            cout << "->Created Socket Successfuly...connecting to server\n";
            if (connect(connectSocket, Results->ai_addr, Results->ai_addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR){
                cout << "->Connected To Server Successfuly\n";
                string Message;
                while (true){
                    cout << "\n->Enter A Message :";
                    getline(cin, Message);          
                    if (send(connectSocket, Message.c_str(), sizeof(Message), 0) != SOCKET_ERROR){
                        cout << "MESSAGE IS SENT\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to give more details, where in relation to the internet is your server (do you have one) , where is your client(s)? Do you have NATs, firewalls, proxies etc.

Comment: I don't have a server, I just want to know how to make my program able to send sockets over the internet to another machine that has the server program and  that is not on the same network. for now my chat application works but if I change the server ip from 127.0.0.1 to another internet protocol it won't work.

Comment: is the other machine on the internet or is it in someone elses network (ie their house or work). If its on the internet then you can probably open a TCP connection to it, but be aware that if you are inside a corporate network you might get blocked. If the destination is in somebody elses network then you need to set up port forwarding. OR write the app as a rendezvous type app

Comment: 'Send sockets over the Internet' is meaningless. 127.0.0.1 is not an Internet protocol. Unclear what you're asking, and too broad.

Comment: you really need to give more details. Where the 2 machines are , what addresses you are using, what error you get etc.

Comment: I've Added two scripts if a basic server-client sockets program to show you what I mean , if I change the address in the server from 127.0.0.1 to an actual online internet protocol it will not bind the socket and I want to know how to make it work.

Comment: and what I mean by two machines is any two computers that one of them holds the server and the other holds the client.

Comment: where is 41.143.215.79

Comment: 41.143.215.7 is the machine that holds the server program/script.

Comment: 'Will not bind the socket' is not a problem description. There is no proper error checking here: if you get an error should should at least call `perror().` C++ is not a scripting language and these are not scripts. You've already been told once that 127.0.0.1 is not an Internet protocol. It is impossible for anyone to understand you if you continue to misuse standard terminology, and if you continue not to provide actual error numbers or error messages.

Comment: I think my problem is clear no need to be hostile , I just want to get this to work with two computers that are not on the same local network and that are connected to the internet , one computer holds  the client and it sends a message to another computer that holds the server. when I use the ip 41.143.215.7 it won't work .

Comment: 'Won't work' is not a problem description either, and you are continuing to miss the point. Your problem is *not* clear without an actual error message or error number, and I've already told you how to produce it. I will hint that you can't bind to an IP address that is not associated with a network interface of the local host, and you don't need to, as per the comment below by @immibis.

Comment: I checked Last Error After binding socket and I Got Error Number 10049

Comment: Have you considered looking it up? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14366048/207421).

Answer (score 1):

Do it just the same way you did it on your local machine.

Sockets are sockets. That's rather the whole point.

Just ensure that your home network is configured in such a way that the traffic can pass between your two machines; usually a home network employs NAT, in which case you need to forward a port through your router.

No idea what "UDP wall punching" is or where it comes into this.

Any further information will require a schematic of your network and a detailed plan for your intended use case.

Comment: It doesn't work if I do the same thing I did on my local machine If I try to bind the socket to another IP different than 127.0.0.1 I get an error.

Comment: its not fair saying its the same, it really isnt. 99% of the time talking over the internet from machine a to machine b is not just a case of opening a tcp pipe. Almost certainly one or more of the players is not directly addrressable

Comment: @TahaElkhaoua Just bind it to 0.0.0.0, which is a special address that means "any address on this computer" (in the case of binding).

Comment: @pm100: Yet the actual program code will be the same.

Comment: unless he has to change it to use a rendezvous server solution. if he cant get a to talk to b then he has to implement a talks to x and b talks to x