# boost asio udp error 10049 on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, udp, asio

I am trying to connect to another machine via udp using Boost Asio. I tested the connection via some tool and I could send and receive data smoothly. However, when I use my own code, it fails.

The same code works on Ubuntu but not on MS Windows.

This the code:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
socket_.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
socket_.bind(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(
                     boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip_), port_));
```

I got error `10049` during binding. I found some solutions for this error like this one: [bind() fails with windows socket error 10049](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366048/bind-fails-with-windows-socket-error-10049)

However, how can I apply them in Boost Asio?

Comment: Is the content of `ip_` referring to a valid local endpoint IP address?

Comment: yes sure both ip and port are valid an were tested using some tool

Comment: On Windows, check out your local interfaces via `ipconfig`. If the IP address specified there is not listed, it will not work. Alternatively, just ommit the IP address in the endpoint definition and thus bind to `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: @Jodocus It is not there.. may you please just elaborate a bit why it is not here or how should I bring it there.. Many thanks!

Comment: It totally depends on your network configuration. Maybe this is a local IP assigned by the gateway DHCP which may change now and then and cannot be hard coded. Is there any reason on not to use `INADDR_ANY`?

Comment: @Jodocus no actually, I am just very newbie to networking and wanted to know the reason. Thank you very much for your time.. I will try it

Comment: @Jodocus Thank you very much, it worked! Please may you prompt your comment to an answer so I can accept it.