# sendto message fails using winsock

Tags: c, visual-studio, sockets, winsock

I'm trying to work with a socket example to send a message through udp to another device from my laptop. The device port is 1600 and its address is "172.10.1.2". The code below is an example from the winsock support page. Using a protocol analyzer I can see: "protocol: UDP, the data sent and the address from the source and the destination. However this only works when I take out the binding part of the code below. If I include the binding code it shows an error 10038. I saw a similar question here [bind() fails with windows socket error 10049](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366048/bind-fails-with-windows-socket-error-10049) I used memset on the sockaddr_in  struct, but I still have the same problem. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks. I'm also working in C using visual studio.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{

    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    SOCKET my_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in service;

    unsigned short Port = 1600;

    char SendBuf[1024] = "Look Here";
    int BufLen = 1024;

    memset(&service, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------
    // Create a socket for sending data
    my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (my_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    // Set up the RecvAddr structure with the IP address of
    // the receiver (in this example case ""172.10.1.2")
    // and the specified port number.
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_port = htons(Port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.10.1.2", &service.sin_addr);
    //RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.10.1.2");

     // Bind the socket.
    iResult = bind(my_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf("bind failed with error %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(my_socket);
    }
    wprintf(L"bind returned success\n");

    //---------------------------------------------
    // Send a datagram to the receiver
    wprintf(L"Sending a datagram to the receiver...\n");

    iResult = sendto(my_socket, SendBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(my_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    // When the application is finished sending, close the socket.
    wprintf(L"Finished sending. Closing socket.\n");
    iResult = closesocket(my_socket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    // Clean up and quit.
    wprintf(L"Exiting.\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get

> bind returned success
> Sending a datagram to the receiver...
> sendto failed with error: 10038

The code that I used to start my project is on the bottom side of this article. Just changed lines

```
//RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.10.1.2"); for 
 inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.10.1.2", &service.sin_addr);
```

and

```
ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); to 
my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-bind

Comment: That's weird output, why was "Sending a datagram to the receiver..." not printed?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update my console. now it shows the right output.

Comment: I think the problem is `bind`. What socket are you binding to? As per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-bind) `bind()` should associate local address with the socket. I think there should be two socket addresses, one you bind with locally, and the other to which to you send data to.

Comment: I'm using that example for my code. The main difference is that I used inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.10.1.2", &service.sin_addr); instead of  //RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.10.1.2"); because it would throw me an error. Also instead of IPPROTO_TCP I'm using IPPROTO_UDP

Comment: Which example are you talking about? Is this code for client or server? Please include all necessary information in the post.

Comment: My coded is based on the code from the link you provided.

Comment: Please include any relevant links in the post itself.

Comment: I added the link you required.

Comment: Is 172.10.1.2 the receiver IP? Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock for creating client and server side sockets.

Comment: UPD in an unconnected protocol, so the socket is only bound to its local address. The sender must not bind to the address of the receiver...

Comment: You are right guys, I've been looking at the code for the server instead of the client. No need for binding .Thanks.